# MVC Controller and data received

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am trying to send json to my mvc action controller, I searched and researched on the web, but I always receive the object in my controller with all "null" fieds.
I tryed to send a string instead then an object but same result, a null string.
I really don't know what could be wrong:

Class:

```
namespace TestUser.Models
{
    public class User
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Sex { get; set; }
        public string Transfer { get; set; }
        public string PercTransf { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CheckUser(  User dati)
    {

        if (dati != null)
        {

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dati.Name))
                return Json("Insert the name");
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dati.Surname))
                return Json("Insert the surname");
            if (dati.Sex != "m" && dati.Sex != "f")
                return Json("Insert the sex");

            return Json("OK");
        }
        else
        {
           return Json("No valid data");
        }

    }
```

Ajax:

```
function checkAndSaveData() {
        var obj = new Object();
        obj.Name = $("#nome").val();
        obj.Surname = $("#cognome").val();
        obj.Email = $("#email").val();
        obj.Sex = $('#selectSesso').find(":selected").val();
        obj.Transfer = "no";
        obj.PercTransf = "0";
        if ($('#trasferte:checked').val() == "on") {
            obj.Transfer = "si";
            obj.PercTransf = $("#tempotrasf").val();
        };

        $.ajax({
           type: 'post',
           dataType: 'json',
           url: '@Url.Action("CheckUser")',
           data: JSON.stringify({ obj }),
           success: function (json) {
                if (json == "ok") {
                    $.ajax({
                       type: 'post',
                       dataType: 'json',
                       url: "@Url.Action("Save")",

                       success: function (json) {
                           if (json == "ok") {
                               alert();
                           } else {
                               alert(json);
                           }
                       },
                   });
               } else {
                   alert(json);
               }
           },
        });



    }
```

Comment: wo wo wo... hold on.. what is this -> `return Json(dati);` on the begging of `CheckUser` method? I will somehow approve that, if it's only for test purposes.

Comment: `url: dataObject`? `data: { json: ... }`? Why?

Comment: Also you need to change `data: { "json": JSON.stringify(obj) },` to `data: { dati: JSON.stringify(obj) },`

Comment: the first return was only for debugging and check object values, I should remove after solve problem

Comment: @Drake What is this -> `url: dataObject,`?

Comment: I changed it during all my attempts to solve the problem, I just fixed, the original was @Url.Action("CheckUser"),

Comment: Also I saw object, that you want to pass to controller, is not `obj` it's `dataObject ` and you don't need to stringify it one more time. So change `data: { dati: JSON.stringify(obj) } ,` to `data: { dati: dataObject } ,`

Comment: I changed it with data: { dati: dataObject } but it's still an empty object

Comment: You do not need `contentType: 'application/json',` and you do not need to stringify your object - its just `data: obj,` and remove the `contentType` option. And since the first line in your method is `return Json(dati);` which exits the method, all the following code is pointless - it will never be executed

Comment: you can change data part to data: JSON.stringify(obj), then you will get it as model object in your controller method

Comment: Please update your question with your latest code.

Comment: I just updated.

Comment: @Drake, you did what Luke suggested, which doesn't work. I'm going to undelete my answer. This line is causing the error `data: { JSON.stringify(obj) },`. Should be `data: JSON.stringify({ dati: obj }),`. Because in your controller you have `public ActionResult CheckUser(User dati)`.

Comment: modified, now I receive this in fiddler:{"dati":{"Name":"da","Surname":"sad","Email":"da","Sex":"m","Transfer":"si","PercTransf":"4"}} But my controller still receive empty object

Comment: @derloopkat this is the current code, except what you told me in previous comment. When I tell empty object I mean I receive a valid object with all proprieties set to null

Comment: @Drake, in your original code there was a contentType value in Ajax call. Why did you remove it?

Comment: @derloopkat  Yes, it is, I removed contenttype by suggest of user eho told it's unuseful

Comment: @Drake, the code I've published works but if contentType is removed then I get nulls again.

Comment: @derloopkat I've it as in your code, but I still have all proprieties set to null, I've both contenttype and datatype

Comment: @Drake, there should be something different in your code, just like last time. If you copy my code in a new project it works. I have tested it.

Answer (score 0):

There were many edits in the question so I'm going to publish full code. This worked for me when testing.

**Javascript code**

```
var obj = new Object();
obj.name = "name";
obj.surname = "cognome";
obj.email = "email";
obj.sex = 'm';
obj.transfer = "no";
obj.perctrasf = "0";

$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: '@Url.Action("CheckUser")',
    data: JSON.stringify({ dati: obj }),
    success: function (json) {
        if (json == "ok") {
            alert("ok");
        } else {
            alert(json);
        }
    },
});
```

**Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CheckUser(User dati)
    {
        return Json(dati);
    }
```

**Model**

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Sex { get; set; }
    public string Transfer { get; set; }
    public string PercTransf { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I just updated, I send this JSON in my request, but still empty object; {"dati":{"name":"sad","surname":"asd","email":"dsa","sex":"m","transfer":"si","PercTrasf":"2"}}

Comment: @Drake, I have tested my code and worked. There must be something else. Are you sure class User is the one you published in your post? (if you have fields instead of properties the class cannot be bound and you'd get nulls) Also there are missing quotation marks in that line `url: @Url.Action("CheckUser"),`, should be `url: '@Url.Action("CheckUser")',`

Comment: I only updated capital letters in both class and object.

Comment: Do they look like `public string Name { get; set; }` or `public string Name;` ? I'm asking again because this causes the issue you're reporting. Need to declare properties instead of fields, otherwise class cannot be mapped.

Comment: namespace TestUser.Models
{
    public class Utente
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Sex { get; set; }
        public string Transfer { get; set; }
        public string PercTransf { get; set; }
    }
}

Comment: @Drake, the last version you published has contentType missing. The dataType is what you receive, but contentType is what is being sent. This information is essential.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be sending the dataObject object in the ajax request.

Try:
 data: { JSON.stringify(obj) }

Also, the object you pass in the data field of the ajax request doesn't need to be on a 'dati' property of an object.

MVC should figure out the rest!

I always use fiddler for debugging issues like this to check the json your sending in the http request is as you'd imagine :)

Comment: I used fiddler and removed "dati", this is what I have in the request (I changed names with capital letters in class and oblect): {"obj":{"Name":"das","Surname":"sda","Email":"da","Sex":"m","Transfer":"no","PercTransf":"0"}}

Comment: try: {"Name":"das","Surname":"sda","Email":"da","Sex":"m",‌​"Transfer":"no","Per‌​cTransf":"0"}

Answer (score 0):

your class properties and javascript properties should be same, then your controller action parameter name should match with jason string. so use like this `JSON.stringify({"dati": obj });`